# About the issue that the character string is broken in TCP/IP communication between different machines

Tags: python, swift, sockets, networking, tcp

I tried TCP/IP communication between the same machine and TCP/IP communication between different machines.

First of all, I tried communication in the same Windows machine.The server and client code used is:

**TCP_server.py**

```
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind(('', 50001))
    s.listen(1)
    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with conn:
            while True:
                data = conn.recv(30000)
                if not data:
                    break
                if len(data.decode('utf-8')) < 35:
                    print("error")
                    break
                print(data.decode('utf-8')+"\n")
```

**TCP_client.py**

```
# -*- coding : UTF-8 -*-

import socket

target_ip = "192.168.1.5"
target_port = 50001
buffer_size = 4096

tcp_client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

tcp_client.connect((target_ip,target_port))

message = b'123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930\n'

while True:
    tcp_client.send(message)
```

The IP address of my Windows machine is 192.168.1.5, so the above code works. And it executed successfully without any error. The printed string is shown in the image below.

[image]

But when I tried to communicate with Mac and Windows using the exact same code, I had a problem. I used a Mac for the client and Windows for the server.The character string output on the server side is as follows.

[image]

As you can see from the image above, it is normally printed normally, but sometimes a line break is made and the character string is divided.

And my server-side code says that if the number of characters is less than 35, it will print error. However, error is not printed in this execution result.In other words, communication is not performed twice, but line breaks are inserted in one communication.

Is it possible to avoid this problem? Do I always have to be aware of line breaks when sending from another machine over TCP/IP?

I'm only using Python in this sample, but I had a similar problem using iOS's Swift for client-side code. So I would like to know a general solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no line break added by transmission of the data. This line break is instead added by the server code:

```
            print(data.decode('utf-8')+"\n")
```

Both the `print` itself causes a line break and then you also add another one.

In general you are assuming that each `send` has a matching `recv`. This assumption is wrong. TCP is a byte stream and not a message stream and the payloads from multiple `send` might be merged together to reduce the overhead of sending and it might also cause a "split" into a single "message".

This is especially true when sending traffic between machines since the bandwidth between the machines is less than the local bandwidth and the MTU of the data layer is also much smaller.

Given that you have to first collect your "messages" at the server side. Only after you've got a complete "message" (whatever this is in your case) you should `decode('utf-8')`. Otherwise your code might crash when trying to decode a character which has a multi-byte UTF-8 encoding but where not all bytes were received yet.

Comment: Thank you. Message fragmentation is an unavoidable problem, and I can't solve this problem just by modifying the client-side code, right? And I need to modify the server side code.

Comment: @taichi: There is no real message fragmentation here since there is no actual concept of a message in your code. You only send a stream of bytes since you are using TCP directly - the message behind this is only in your mind. You first have to introduce a concept of a message in your client code (like prefixing with a length) and then you can restore the message based on the clients message semantic on the server side.